# Extracting elements inside and between brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string and I would like to extract the elements (xx="yy") and what's between the brackets. Here's an example:

> [caption id="get this" align="and this" width="and this" caption="and
>   this"]this too please[/caption]

I've tried the following code but I'm quite a noob with regex.

```
re.sub(r'\[caption id="(.*)" align="(.*)" width="(.*)" caption="(.*)"\](.*)\[\/caption\]', "tokens: %1 %2 %3 %4 %5", self.content, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not working for you because `.*` is greedy. Try `[^"]*` in its place. `[^"]` means the set of all characters except the quote character. Also, as you've pointed out in the comments, the token syntax, is `\\n`, not `%n`. Try this:

```
re.sub(r'\[caption id="([^"]*)" align="([^"]*)" width="([^"]*)" caption="([^"]*)"\](.*)\[\/caption\]', "tokens: \\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5", self.content, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Do the contents of the caption tag span multiple lines? If they do `.*` won't capture the newlines. You'll need to us something like `[^\x00]*` instead. `[^\x00]` means the set of all charchters except the null character.

```
re.sub(r'\[caption id="([^"]*)" align="([^"]*)" width="([^"]*)" caption="([^"]*)"\]([^\x00]*)\[\/caption\]', "tokens: \\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5", self.content, re.IGNORECASE)
```

On the off chance that your strings can actually legitimately contain null characters, you would need to use the `re.DOTALL` flag instead.

Comment: Depending on your programming language, you may be able to add the NONGREEDY modifier to the expression.

Comment: nice, that did work! I also forgot the token syntax is // not %, and then it worked: re.sub(r'\[caption id="([^"]*)" align="([^"]*)" width="([^"]*)" caption="([^"]*)"\](.*)\[\/caption\]', "tokens: \\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5", self.content, re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: @Clash: I've updated my answer to include the part about the token syntax.

Comment: I've never heard of using `[^\x00]` like that before, and I hope I never do again. ☺  If you really need to match `anything-including-newlines`, and you don't have a DOTALL or single-line option, use the JavaScript convention: `[\s\S]`.  But I would have used `[^\[]` in this case.

Comment: @Alan Moore: `[^x00]` is a widely used technique popularized by Jeffry Friedl's excellent [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124) book. Using it instead of `re.DOTALL` offers more flexibility because you can mix matching newlines and not matching newlines in the same regular expression.

Comment: Can you give me a page number for that?  All I find is a comment (p. 119, 3rd ed.) that `.` doesn't match `\x00` in POSIX flavors.  In Python, `[^\x00]` matches newlines but fails to match the perfectly legal NUL character.  I can see how you would sometimes need this kind of hack (because `(?s)` always affects the whole regex in Python, unlike in most other flavors), but `[^\x00]` still looks like an error to me.

Comment: @Alan Moore: I will look and get back to you. I will admit that my edition of the book is one of the older ones, not the current 3rd edition. I could have sworn I learned it there, though. 95% of what I know about regular expressions came from that book. I'll also admit that it looks rather unsightly. Nulls legitimately appearing in strings? I've only ever seen them as terminators, and not in any modern language.

Comment: I didn't say anyone *uses* NUL in strings, just that they can. ;)  It's a character, like any other: [U+0000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm).

Comment: @Alan Moore: So it turns out I have the 1st edition of Mastering Regular Expressions. It's the dead tree variety so I can't easily search it. But flipping through the index, I just can't find a reference to `[^\x00]`. The closest is pages 78-79 where he mentions the null character, hex ranges, and "Dot vs. a negated character class" all in close proximity. But he doesn't come right out with `[^\x00]`. So I must have picked it up elsewhere. I do apologize for the mis-reference. In any case, it _is_ a widely used trick and well supported across most regex engines you're likely to encounter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3117/discussion-between-alan-moore-and-asaph)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to leverage the power of Python's standard SGML/HTML/XML parsing modules: if it is safe to substitute "[]" for "<>", then you can do this substitution in order to produce valid XML, and do the parsing with the standard library XML parsing functions:

```
import string
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

text = '[caption id="get this" align="and this" width="and this" caption="and this"]this too please[/caption]'
xml_text = string.translate(text, string.maketrans('[]', '<>'))  # Conversion to XML
parsed_text = ET.fromstring(xml_text)  # Parsing

# Extracted information
print "Text part:", parsed_text.text
print "Values:", parsed_text.attrib.values()
```

This correctly print:

```
Text part: this too please
Values: ['and this', 'and this', 'get this', 'and this']
```

The advantage of this approach is that (1) it uses a standard module that many people know; (2) it explicitly shows what you want to do; and (3) you can readily extract more information, handle more complicated values (including values that contain double quotes…), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this?

```
re = '[caption id="get this" align="and this" width="and this" caption="and this"]this too please[/caption]'
re.gsub(/([a-z]*)=\"(.*?)\"/i) do |m|
    puts "#{$1} = #{$2}
end
```